# Display WebPage without using mobile connection

Tags: android, webview, html

I am using the WebView of Android so that I will not have to program the zoom and scroll. I have the web page that I want in the assets folder and here is my code. Each time I run in the emulator I am getting the error, *no such file or directory*. My question is what do I need to change in order for this to work?

Just updated my .java to this and now I receive a force close when I press *button1* and my XML is the same as below.

**OK I fixed that last part and now all that is happening is I get a blank screen once the app is opened.**

```
package com.DS;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CheatMathActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);


final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){

            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/stuffyoumustknowcoldforapcalc.htm");

    } });  
} 

}
```

Ok Here is my XML, before the added WebView I had somewhat of a home activity that had two buttons and a textview, once I add the WebView all that the graphical layout shows is a grey screen that says WebView in the center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#4876ff" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:text="AP Calculus" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="More Coming Soon!" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFAFA"
    android:text="If you have any questions or want to report a bug, feel free to email                        me at fgoyer3856@gmail.com
                    Thank you!" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Welcome to Math Cheat Sheet!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a webview on your layout. and on your activity load your html asset like this.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/stuffyoumustknowcoldforapcalc.htm");
```

And don't forget to put file `stuffyoumustknowcoldforapcalc.htm` in folder named `assets`.

```
package com.DS;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class CheatMathActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/stuffyoumustknowcoldforapcalc.htm");

        } });  
    } 


}
```

Comment: if I put a copy of my main.xml in the questions, would you edit it and show me what you mean by putting a webview in? I attempted doing that but I had a problem with the webview overriding the relative layout I already had.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a sample layout having webview. If you have problem with layout, you can show us.

Comment: I have another problem :) You have been a huge help so far. Check my updated question

Comment: on your layout your webviews id is `android:id="@+id/webView1"` but your reference at activity is `findViewById(R.id.webView);`  So it is not finding your webview on layout and it is becoming null. You need to write correct id which you mentioned on layout which is webview1.  `WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);`

Comment: You are helping a lot but it hasn't quite worked yet. Check my updated question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you use an Intent (as you posted above) a new external browser  instance shows up and loads the `Uri` set in the `Intent` instead of using your own `WebView`.
In order to achieve what you're asking you have to get a reference to the `WebView` inside your activity layout and then load your page. Furthermore, if you want to load your page from your `assets/` folder you should use `AssetManager` instead, and the `WebView.loadData()` method. Your `onCreate()` method should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  // get a reference to the webview
  final WebView wV = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

  // get page content from assets/your_page.html as a String
  InputStream is = getAssets().open("your_page.html");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  String line;
  while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append("\n");
  }
  is.close();
  final String html = sb.toString();

  // get a reference to the button
  Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){

      // load html string into your WebView
      wV.loadData( html, "text/html", "utf-8" );
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: How would I initiate this off of a button press instead of onCreate?

Comment: I just edited my answer according to your request. Hope it helps.

Comment: mr_archano Any reason opening and reading file? All files on assets folder can accessible directly as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Well, IMHO opening/reading the file can be a more robust solution. I'm always scared of using "hardcoded" based on some unofficial/undocumented feature (the file:///android_asset/ base URL in this case): a future Android release (or a customized version as well) can easily break it :)

Comment: Ok, if it is the only reason (thought you need some manipulation on text before loading on webview), it is documented and on offical android developer groups this is most given example. No need to afraid.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html   `public void setAllowFileAccess (boolean allow)

Since: API Level 3
Enable or disable file access within WebView. File access is enabled by default. Note that this enables or disables file system access only. Assets and resources are still accessible using file:///android_asset and file:///android_res.`

Comment: @Nesim Razon: Thanks for the insight: I wasn't aware of this piece of doc, even if I was aware of that url :). Like I stated before, this is only my personal interpretation of "best practices" and my personal approach in order to provide robust solutions in my code. Feel free to downvote my answer in case ;)

Comment: No need to downvote, you approach is not wrong, I was just curious about if there a special reason that I didn't think of so I asked. Thanks.